# ArcGIS - if clause in the field editor with python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, syntax

I have 2 columns in my table. 
"dB1" and "dB2" 
Now I want to calculate a third columnn "dB3" depending of the entries in column "dB1" and "dB2"

if "dB1" or "dB2" have an entry of "0" I want to calculate: "dB1" + "dB2"

if neither "dB1" nor "dB2" have an entry of "0" I want to calculate: 10*log(10^(0,1*"dB1")+10*(0,1*dB2))

I struggle with the syntax and the if clause here...
Can someone give me the code as I theoretically know how it should be done but can't work around the syntax in python...

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you mean the CalculateField tool when you refer to 'field editor with Python,' and you are in a locale that uses comas as a decimal mark (ie 0,1*dB1 = 0.1*dB1).

You can do this with a single expression:

```python
!dB1! + !dB2! if 0 in (!dB1!,!dB2!) else 10*math.log(10**(0.1*!dB1!)+10*(0.1*!dB2!))
```

This uses a shorthand form of if/else:

```
<condition if true> if condition> else <condition if false>
```

`0 in (!dB1!,!dB2!)` is a short way of checking if either value is 0 and the rest is your formula.

This also uses uses the default base (e) for the `math.log` function which is the natural logarithm. If you wanted a different base, you will need to specify it to `log`.

Also note that field calculator uses ! to surround field names, where the SQL expression uses " (for many formats).

Comment: Thank you, now I am so far that the calculator calculates something....but not correct?


If I take an example for a line: 
DB_Low: 75
DB_LOW_1: 55 


Result: 173


But if I calculate manually it should result in: 75.04


This is my code:
!DB_Low! + !DB_LOW_1! if 0 in ( !DB_Low! , !DB_LOW_1! ) else 10*math.log(10**(0.1* !DB_Low! )+10**(0.1* !DB_LOW_1! ))

Comment: Ok I got it now! (I had to use log10)

--> Question answered! Thanks!

Comment: @M.S. I'm glad it worked for you...that's what I was referring to when I said `log` uses the default base.